# SSIS package with CHANGE TRACKING keeps missing records

Tags: sql-server, ssis, change-tracking

I have an SSIS package using CHANGE TRACKING that runs every 5 minutes to perform one way synchronization on a table.

These are the DB's involved:

- DestDB
- SourceDB

DestDB contains a table called TableSyncVersions that is used to keep track of the most recent Sync version used to extract information from the table in SourceDB. This Sync Version is used for the next execution of the package to get the next batch of data.

SourceDB has Snapshot Isolation enabled and the CT Query is being executed by an "OLE DB Source" in SSIS. The Query is as follows:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
BEGIN TRAN;

--Using OLE DB parameters to capture the current version within the transaction
SELECT ? = CAST(CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() AS NVARCHAR)

SELECT ct.KeyColumn1
     , ct.KeyColumn2
     , ct.KeyColumn3
     , st.Column1
     , st.Column2
     , st.Column3
     , st.Column4    
     , ct.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION
FROM TABLE1 AS st 
--Using OLE DB Parameters to reference the version # saved in TableSyncVersions 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TABLE1, ?) AS ct
    ON avq.KeyColumn1 = ct.KeyColumn1
       AND avq.KeyColumn2 = ct.KeyColumn2
       AND avq.KeyColumn3 = ct.KeyColumn3

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Here is a screen shot of the Control Flow for this package:

[image: Change Tracking SSIS Control Flow]

At least once a day, the package misses 5-20 records even though it ran without error, the records are missed at different times everyday. Has anyone experienced anything like this with Change Tracking before?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Tory Hill

Comment: Approach seems sound... How long does the package take to run? I presume less than 5 minutes so no worries about the package trying to start while the current invocation is running. If you look at a scenario where you missed data - was it the whole batch that isn't there or is it some portion of the rows?

Comment: The package averages at 60 seconds, so there is no interference. The missing records are just a portion of the rows, in some cases the missed records have a SYS_CHANGE_VERSION in sequence with the version number that would have been used to capture them.